# Should I choose excel spreadsheet or a database as the source of a web app?

Tags: database, excel, web

It might look like an odd question but the fact is I currently have a existing spreadsheet with data, not a lot, of hundreds of rows. What I am willing to do is a web app provide "search" interface for data (maybe some more advanced features in future, like data update). Thus I have two options:

- I can programme on top of the excel, i.e. read/write spreadsheet directly
- Or I can export the whole data to a database, say mysql, and work around it. The data conversion does take time but will not be very bad.

What I need to consider is:

- if it is easy to code, for either solution. I have some experiences coding C with mysql but never touch Excel programming. If the learning curve is too steep I would rather spend days to export all data to database.
- if it is easy to maintain. Day to day work like search or update will be done through web once the app is on. It needs to be stable and easy to expand. More features like comparing different columns or, reformating some data and emailing out could be considered.

Any suggestions? And, what language, libraries or framework I should pick up?

Comment: I'd take a look at SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Comment: Is this a answer to the question? (I know what sqlite does and I know a bit SQL) Basically I want some details comparison/clarifying between Excel and database from the aspect of being a data source. I can not see why someone think this topic is not helpful. It is a real problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll definitely want to use a database. Excel wasn't made for quickly accessing data, it was made for calculations. Trying to build on it will likely cause lots of hassle and lag.

Comment: Thanks could you give a bit more details? Like some example how painful it can be some specific application...

Comment: With a proper database, you can retrieve data just by installing a plugin and using one line of script for each item/group of items you want to withdraw (case in point: PHP with SQL). If you used Excel, you would have to find some way to decode the data, which probably means building a frontend to some library, then sort what you want out of the metadata every time you withdraw data.

Comment: I think I have some feeling...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should definitely choose database.

In my experience programming against Excel is very painful. Tools for accessing database are usually easy to use.

If you do not have any experience with web programming, I would suggest you to use PHP with MySQL.  It is the easiest to start with and if you do not need anything complex, it would do totally fine.